# Motivation for integrals over scalar field

Tags: temperature, path-integral, integration

I'm looking for good examples of physical motivation for integrals over scalar field.

Here is an example I've seen:

> If you want to know the final temperature of an object that travels through a medium described with a temperature field then you'll need a line integral​.

It appears to me that the final temperature of our object would depend not only on its path (i.e. the image of the curve) but on the speed as well (if it spends a lot of time in an area with low temperature, it won't be reflected in its path but it clearly would be reflected in its final temperature). Thus, it looks like the value of the integral would be parametrization-dependend (but it shouldn't).

So I have two questions:

1. Am I right that the temperature example is off?
2. What are some good examples of physical motivation for integrals over scalar field? (If possible, don't assume any knowledge of physics.)

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you need an  integral over a scalar field each time you want to know the total amount of an extensive value fiven in the field: total mass, total load, etc from the density field...

To compute how a light ray is absorbed as traversing a semi-opaque media, you how have to write the integral giving the optical depth along the ray.

etc.